# How to apply multiple functions to a dataframe column on multiple cores in python

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing

I have a pandas dataframe and want to apply three different functions on one of the columns in parallel on multiple cores. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'col1': ['LA','Boston','Phoenix','Toronto'], 'col2': [2,3,4,5]},
columns=['col1', 'col2'])

def function1(x):
    return(x**2)

def function2(x):
    return(x**3)

def function(x):
    return(x**4)
```

I want to apply the three functions to column 'col2' in parallel, on multiple cores and the results to be new columns in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Ivan, it doesn't clear what do you mean by "parallel".

**SIMPLE ANSWER**

the simplest code to do that is the following:

```
def function1(x):
    return(x**2)

def function2(x):
    return(x**3)

def function(x):
    return(x**4)

df = pd.DataFrame(
{'col1': ['LA','Boston','Phoenix','Toronto'], 'col2': [2,3,4,5]},
columns=['col1', 'col2'])

df['func1_col2'] = df['col2'].apply(function1, axis=1) # axis=1: 1 or ‘columns’: apply function to each row...
df['func2_col2'] = df['col2'].apply(function2, axis=1)
df['func3_col2'] = df['col2'].apply(function3, axis=1)
```

As a result, you will get three more columns in your DataFrame.
Here, [details](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for apply function.

### **PARALLEL**

If you want to make it in parallel — you need to use a [multiprocessing tool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).
If so, please, update your question and you will get an answer on how to make it in parallel with Python (3.10+).

Comment: Thank you! I want to make it parallel on multiple cores.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this to make sure we iterate only once.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {'col1': ['LA', 'Boston', 'Phoenix', 'Toronto'], 'col2': [2, 3, 4, 5]},
    columns=['col1', 'col2'])


def function1(x):
    return (x ** 2)

def function2(x):
    return (x ** 3)


def function(x):
    return (x ** 4)

def all_fn(row):
    return function1(row["col2"]), function2(row["col2"]), function(row["col2"]),

df[["col3", "col4", "col5"]] = df.apply(all_fn, axis=1, result_type="expand")
```

Comment: Thank you! I want to apply these functions parallel on different cores.